# Emacs and Windows manager keyboard shortcuts without Windows key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, emacs, windows-key

I found a classic [M-Series keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_M_keyboard) and I want to use it. However, it does not have a Windows key (AKA Super key); only <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>. My keyboard shortcuts are cluttered as-is, since I try to control both Emacs and the Windows manager (Gnome) entirely from the keyboard. I rely on the Super key to identify Windows manager shortcuts.

How can I perform keyboard-centric work without the Super key?

Answer (score 1):

On my Model M, I turned my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key into a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (this is great for avoiding "Emacs pinky"), then turned my left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key into a Super or "Windows" key.  I use Caps Lock very seldomly, so I just have it bound to  a key combination.